# What happens if Instruct points to a Z-move?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Suppose the following case:

1. Salamance used Draco Meteor with Z-crystal.
2. Oranguru used Instruct to point to the Salamance.

In this case, does Instruct point to Draco Meteor, or one more Z-move, or end up in a failure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my own personal experience, Instruct fails when used on a partner who just used a Z-move.

This is supported by [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Instruct_(move))

> Instruct will fail if the target has not made any move, is in the middle of Bide, Focus Punch, Beak Blast, Shell Trap, or a consecutively executed move, or when the instructed move's PP is depleted. **It will also fail if the target's most recent move is** Instruct itself, Bide, Focus Punch, Beak Blast, Shell Trap, Struggle, a move that requires recharging (such as Hyper Beam), a move with a charging turn (such as Dig or Skull Bash), a move that calls another move (such as Metronome), or **a Z-Move**.